# TS_ACT_VALUE Calculation in Project Server

Tags: project-server

I am trying to use c# to create timesheet entries in Project Server and running across a problem with saving the number of hours for the timesheet line on a certain day.

If I look at the dataset, there is a property for `TS_ACT_VALUE`. If I use 1 hour it shows 60000.  Does anyone know what the calculation is to get that value, or another method of saving the number of hours worked on a timesheet line item?

Answer (score 0):

John,

Per the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvctimesheet.timesheetdataset.actualsrow.ts_act_value.aspx the TS_ACT_VALUE column "represents the actual cost recorded for this timesheet line item."

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of the actual definition of the column but was more interested in how they get the calculation for it.  when i look at sample data the column is divisible by 1000

Answer (score 0):

it simply because the time is reprensented in milisecond...   simply multiply your value in a hour by 60000